# Cancel/dismiss notification on icon

Tags: android, onesignal

I'm using OneSignal to display notifications to my user. The notifications work fine but, I noticed that if I cancel the notification "swiping" it in the notification bar then the notification remains for ever, here is a image showing the notification on the app icon that I would like to dismiss as soon as the application is opened:

[image: icon]

I have seen this question, showing that I can dismiss the notification by doing:

```
NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
if (nMgr!=null) {
    nMgr.cancelAll();
}
```

But this cancels the notification in that notification bar, but the notification on the app icon remain, any idea how I can cancel it as soon as my application is opened?

**EDIT 1:**

I added the above in `OnCreate`, also in `OnResume` as mentioned in the answer below, but the `1` still gets displayed on the app icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that with OneSignal I can disable badges by adding the following in my manifest:

```
<application ...>

    <meta-data android:name="com.onesignal.BadgeCount" android:value="DISABLE" />

</application>
```

Starting with 8.0 (API level 26), notification badges can be disabled by calling the [following](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/badges):

```
String id = "my_channel_01";
CharSequence name = getString(R.string.channel_name);
String description = getString(R.string.channel_description);
int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW;
NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(id, name, importance);
mChannel.setDescription(description);
mChannel.setShowBadge(false);

NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
```

With [this](https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger) library I can also set badge numbers manually after disabling them. Note, this only supports certain manufactured devices (Samsung, LG, Sony and HTC).

Answer (score -2):

the above code is perfect but the thing you need to do is you need to add this code inside the `onResume()`
Like

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nm.cancelAll();
}
```

thats do the trick for you . :)

Comment: By using this, it gets cancelled in the navigation bar but the `1` still remains on the icon.

Comment: @KunalNikam What is the difference between your answer and what is asked/said in the question?

Comment: @HB.Do some research before downvoting anyones answer 
the same code works for me thats why i put it here 
and at the time posting question he did not mention 
where exactly he put above code after my answer he edited question
also in above comment he clearly says he use it in oncreate . 
so Do some research before puting anything here.

Comment: @KunalNikam in his question he stated that he tried exactly what you say he should do. I had the exact same issue and if you go read the One Signal documentation you will see that @ClassA is correct. Also, you stated that he should use it in `onResume` and not in `onCreate` - you could've explained why. I can't see why placing it in `onResume` will make a difference.